# Artifactory warns about "Path checksum calculation job" after upgrade to 5.8.3

Tags: artifactory, sha256

I just migrated our OSS instance of Artifactory from 5.4.5 to 5.8.3 (standalone, using Derby)

I followed the recommendations at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory and basically did:

- Actual upgrade to 5.8.3 (stop, replace some files, start)
- SHA-256 job to calculate checksums on existing artifacts (stop, add property to confiuguration, start)

Both worked fine and the server is back up and running smoothly.

However, I now have a warning in `logs/artifactory.log` on instance start up

> 2018-01-24 16:12:07,633 [art-exec-4] [WARN ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJobDelegate:110) - Path Checksum calculation job (for existing artifacts) has been disabled and will not run, there are still 5348 artifacts without path checksum values in the database. Future version of Artifactory may enforce this conversion as a prerequisite for upgrades.

I cannot find any more substantial explanation for this warning.

I am thinking that this is related to the artifacts layout on the file system (cf. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Checksum-Based+Storage#Checksum-BasedStorage-Overview). The artifacts are still laid according to their SHA-1checksums rather than their SHA-256 checksums.

Is my assumption correct? How do I "fix" this warning...

**EDIT**: Some more tests requested by @Ariel:

- Restarting the server doesn't help, the warning is still there
- Reenabling the migration job and restarting the server doesn't help either

`echo "artifactory.sha2.migration.job.enabled=true" >> etc/artifactory.system.properties`

Looking at the logs related to this migration, it seems that the migration job thinks that everything has been migrated, and the startup check finds 2,000 artifacts that should be migrated.

> $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/sha256_migration.log

```
2018-01-24 14:39:53,982 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:284) - artifactory.Sha256MigrationJob#83253c93-33ec-4c52-bc61-d2d33942dc28: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-24 16:12:07,576 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:284) - artifactory.Sha256MigrationJob#6f5c6739-c365-4be2-80a4-d32063a75f8f: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-24 16:12:07,651 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:186) - 3319 artifacts and 3292 binary entries are missing SHA256 values - starting calculation job.
2018-01-24 16:12:07,756 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:121) - SHA256 migration state: 0/3319 artifacts were handled.
[...]
2018-01-24 16:13:58,226 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:121) - SHA256 migration state: 3318/3319 artifacts were handled.
2018-01-24 16:13:58,227 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:270) - SHA256 migration job now filling in for missing SHA256 values for binary entries. Found 1 such entries
2018-01-24 16:14:01,065 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:338) - SHA256 migration job has finished successfully. 3319 artifacts and 1 binary entry calculations were submitted (including retries)
2018-01-24 16:29:06,072 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:284) - artifactory.Sha256MigrationJob#7cdeab66-229d-43a5-a788-301f72c10cc5: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-29 06:04:57,405 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:284) - artifactory.Sha256MigrationJob#2c539185-b7f4-412f-b988-0688e8505649: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-29 10:27:33,655 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:284) - artifactory.Sha256MigrationJob#19afc5d2-c12d-4821-8c1a-808655e8746c: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-29 10:31:39,250 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:284) - artifactory.Sha256MigrationJob#c01bd20d-249a-4c6e-80ff-e26301db7e84: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-29 10:34:57,321 [art-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJob:284) - artifactory.Sha256MigrationJob#32fff21f-04d5-45a4-84d2-58083aaf6593: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
```

> $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/path_checksum_migration.log

```
2018-01-24 14:39:53,982 [art-exec-4] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:284) - artifactory.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob#2f7f690c-dc78-4074-b35f-e5085d41a2f7: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-24 14:39:54,012 [art-exec-4] [WARN ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:111) - Path Checksum calculation job (for existing artifacts) has been disabled and will not run, there are still 5348 artifacts without path checksum values in the database. Future version of Artifactory may enforce this conversion as a prerequisite for upgrades.
2018-01-24 16:12:07,576 [art-exec-4] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:284) - artifactory.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob#4c3a71ed-f389-4bff-a7b9-62d20806b270: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-24 16:12:07,634 [art-exec-4] [WARN ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:111) - Path Checksum calculation job (for existing artifacts) has been disabled and will not run, there are still 5348 artifacts without path checksum values in the database. Future version of Artifactory may enforce this conversion as a prerequisite for upgrades.
2018-01-24 16:29:06,072 [art-exec-4] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:284) - artifactory.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob#8e2c1a01-c3d9-4848-b48a-70813ffd26d1: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-24 16:29:06,127 [art-exec-4] [WARN ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:111) - Path Checksum calculation job (for existing artifacts) has been disabled and will not run, there are still 2029 artifacts without path checksum values in the database. Future version of Artifactory may enforce this conversion as a prerequisite for upgrades.
2018-01-29 06:04:57,405 [art-exec-4] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:284) - artifactory.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob#b7ac1c4a-5dec-4065-a901-bb5a3d2a4b59: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-29 06:04:57,505 [art-exec-4] [WARN ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:111) - Path Checksum calculation job (for existing artifacts) has been disabled and will not run, there are still 2029 artifacts without path checksum values in the database. Future version of Artifactory may enforce this conversion as a prerequisite for upgrades.
2018-01-29 10:27:33,655 [art-exec-4] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:284) - artifactory.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob#74cf399a-1c3b-4b11-a687-cc11b19d2887: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-29 10:27:33,704 [art-exec-4] [WARN ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:111) - Path Checksum calculation job (for existing artifacts) has been disabled and will not run, there are still 2029 artifacts without path checksum values in the database. Future version of Artifactory may enforce this conversion as a prerequisite for upgrades.
2018-01-29 10:31:39,250 [art-exec-4] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:284) - artifactory.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob#ba1c5406-2f49-48f2-a9f2-a9e48c8d7807: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-29 10:31:39,308 [art-exec-4] [WARN ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:111) - Path Checksum calculation job (for existing artifacts) has been disabled and will not run, there are still 2029 artifacts without path checksum values in the database. Future version of Artifactory may enforce this conversion as a prerequisite for upgrades.
2018-01-29 10:34:57,321 [art-exec-4] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:284) - artifactory.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob#b62872c1-4c00-4503-8628-bc2dd38d8c17: all nodes reached minimal version '5.5.0-m001', continuing execution
2018-01-29 10:34:57,372 [art-exec-4] [WARN ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJob:111) - Path Checksum calculation job (for existing artifacts) has been disabled and will not run, there are still 2029 artifacts without path checksum values in the database. Future version of Artifactory may enforce this conversion as a prerequisite for upgrades.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is poorly documented — I had to download the Artifactory OSS source code and grep for the answer — but apparently Path Checksum migration is a completely separate job from SHA-256 migration. 
You want `artifactory.pathChecksum.migration.job.enabled=true` in your `artifactory.system.properties`, I think.

Comment: Well done, this enables the job and the path checksums are calculated on first start.
The message is now gone! Thanks.
I then cleaned up by removing this entry in _artifactory.system.properties_
2018-02-13 09:56:31,625 [art-exec-4] [INFO ] (o.a.s.j.m.p.RepoPathChecksumMigrationJobDelegate:116) - 2029 artifacts are missing repoPathChecksum values - starting calculation job.
[...]

Comment: Thanks. That really helped and it worked like a charm. :)

Comment: NB: There are two jobs:
`artifactory.sha2.migration.job.enabled` and `artifactory.pathChecksum.migration.job.enabled`

Answer (score 2):

The operation of Sha-256 is not being done automatically. You need to manually set it up so it will run. This was done in order not to cause overload on users environments.
If you wish to activate it follow this link:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Checksum-Based+Storage#Checksum-BasedStorage-MigratingtheDatabasetoIncludeSHA-256

Comment: Well this is what I described as the second step of the migration in my original question. I activated the configuration to run this job and restarted the server. Logs in `logs/artifactory.log` say that the SHA-256 checksums were calculated  for all the artifacts. I can provide the relevant lines if that helps.

Comment: It happened to me as well on Artifactory 5.8.1. Once I've restarted the instance it worked. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, please see the details as an Edit to the question